# Pyinstaller gets stuck without an error message

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I'm currently trying to convert a python file into an executable with Pyinstaller.
When I start Pyinstaller with default-settings, it starts working. Python shows CPU/RAM-usage but after a minute it shows a CPU-usage of 0% and seemingly stops working. 
The program is still running though and there is no error message.
I tried converting a 'hello world' program and this worked in a couple of seconds.
My code has about 400 lines, most of them setting up the interface and I import packages like tkinter, numpy, pandas and docx.

Is there an estimate of how long I have to wait/a way to detect what is going wrong?

I'm using Python 3.7 running on Spyder.

**EDIT:**

I didn't get to far towardy my loose end, just adding numpy to the hello world example was too much:

```
import tkinter as tk
import numpy as np



 root = tk.Tk()
 var = 4.5
 var = np.round(var)
 Label = tk.Label(root, text = 'hello world!')
 Label.pack()
 root.mainloop()
```

**EDIT2:**

I switched to cx_freeze which gave error messages and I could get it working

Comment: You have a known-good, and a known-bad case. Start stripping the known-bad case down until it works. That will point you st the problematic code or package.

Comment: Try building it from a .spec file

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: I tried making my way from the known-good example and was quickly stopped. I edited it in my question.

Which settings of a .spec file could be useful to get the problem with Pyinstaller?

Comment: I can live without numpy, so the problem boils down to pandas. 
I tried building from the spec file and putting pandas as a hidden import but this did not work either.
Any ideas what I can try? It just really bugs me that there is no error message, for all related topics I found started with an error message